# Does DbSet.Add() mark all related entities as added or only those in collection properties?

Tags: entity-framework

My understanding about `DbSet.Add(entity)` was that all related entities were supposed to be marked as added and therefore result in inserts at SaveChanges time. However, the code I'm working on it seems I have to manually set the `context.Entry().State` for singular navigation properties that are new entities.

```
var library = new Library();
library.Sections.Add(new Section {Name="Fiction"});
library.Sections.Add(new Section {Name="NonFiction"});
library.Sections.Add(new Section {Name="Reference"});
library.Librarian = new Librarian {Name="Conan"};

context.Libraries.Add(library);
context.SaveChanges()
```

In the simplified code above, shouldn't the 3 new Section entities *and* the new Librarian entity all get inserted? What I'm seeing is that if I don't manually mark the Librarian entity as EntityState.Added there is no insert for it, but the Sections will all be inserted.